# File being used in another process

Tags: c#

I have a background worker that checks file hashes and sizes and compairs with a list. I want to make it so when it checks for the file, if it doesn't exit it will download that then move on with the list, it errors at the following code.

```
using (Stream streamLocal = new FileStream(sFilePathToWriteFileTo, FileMode.Create))
```

I get an error only on some files, it error `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` When there is nothing else using it or unless its trying to download it while checking for it.

Comment: There is far too much code here. Please [edit] your question and reduce it to the minimal amount needed for your problem. Expecting us to wade through that much code to try and figure out what's happening is simply unreasonable.

Comment: I edited. only put the code where it errors out.

Comment: if there is any other code anyone would like let me know.

Comment: Windows thinks there's another process using the file, you think there isn't who do you think is more likely to be correct about that? Note also that this exception can be thrown when it's your _own_ process that already has the file open.

Comment: Im sure it is my own process, I would like a way to not have it get caught.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't care about the error.  So just put it in a try block

```
try
{
    using (Stream streamLocal = new FileStream(sFilePathToWriteFileTo, FileMode.Create))
    {
        ...
    }
}
catch { }
```